# custom attributes in separate coloumn while export? - Magento 2.0.8

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, importexport, export

**short description what I done:**

1. create product attribute set (Chennai)
2. create 21 new product attributes
3. assign to Chennai attribute set
4. set value to attribute while create product
5. export (System->Export->Continue) csv

problem is my new attributes comes under **additional_attributes** column but I am expecting each attribute occupy one column.

Anything need to mention while creating attribute for export related things?

can anyone pointing to me right direction?

Comment: Is new attribute displaying on frontside ?

Comment: thats ok its reflect in frontend, but I need in CSV also, what I do for this

Comment: Cay you please tell me attribute type dropdown or any others ?

Comment: I have try with three different **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner** 1)Dropdown 2)Text Swatch 3)Text Field but all times I get failed to get result in expoerted CSV

Comment: I have try with one text and drop-down attributes but i am getiing attributes value in csv file. I have working in magento (2.0.4).

Comment: oh really :-) I get this attribute under additional_attribute column not in main column, do you get in main column?

Comment: I also get it under additional_attribute column.

Comment: while create attribute I am not mention this attribute is under additional attribute at anywhere. how its get mapping to under additional_attribute? I want it in main attribute colum, because its leads to add unwanted details in more details tab in product detail page. :-) @Patel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38279/discussion-between-bilal-usean-and-s-h-patel).

Comment: This is possible now with bss custom extension

Comment: @BilalUsean please approve the answer that helped you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I found a free Magento 2 extension from [BSS Commerce](https://bsscommerce.com/) which helped me work around this:

- https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-export-custom-product-attributes-in-magento-2/
- https://bsscommerce.com/custom-product-attribute-export-for-magento-2.html

It provides some override code for the `Model\Export\Product` core class which breaks out the `additional_attributes` field into separate columns. In my testing it works on Import and Export.

You do have to configure an Admin setting for the module to tell it which fields to break out into their own columns, but it was easy to set up.

This module saved me some time duplicating their efforts, which was nice, and now the client can provide a normal CSV with attributes in columns, without me having to transform it with a script :)

Answer (score 6):

All custom attributes get appeared under "additional_attributes" header in the export separated by a comma (,). I am using Magento 2.0.7.
[image]

To make these attributes occupy a separate cell, we can add more columns to the CSV.

Comment: I also tried the same and my custom attributes are getting exported under additional_attributes column. Try to find out in csv using search if your attribute is there in any column

Comment: Yes ! As you can see in the attached screenshot, **number_of_colours**  , **wash_instructions** , are our custom attributes. I guess this time Magento2 chose to list all attributes under one roof inside the csv.

Comment: please review my comments already I point out it is come under additional attribute. RJ07, Kumar sorry guys it is my fault. I updated my question please review.

Comment: @KumarA. where is the answer and where you share link for reference ?

Answer (score 6):

**Solution :**

For this Need to do some changes in *vendor\magento\module-catalog-import-export\Model\Export\Product.php* file or override same model file in your custom module .

In `vendor\magento\module-catalog-import-export\Model\Export\Product.php` file add custom_attributes code those you want in separate cell ( not in additional_attributes cell) in **$_exportMainAttrCodes** global array variable line no. 263.

**For example :**

if suppose your export csv file contained

"**collection_year=2014,lining_color=Light,material=Cotton|Wool|Polyester,season=Winter**" value under **additional_attributes** header field for particular product. so add  collection_year, hanger, lining_color & material keys in this $_exportMainAttrCodes array variable like:

```
protected $_exportMainAttrCodes = [
    self::COL_SKU, 
    'name',
    'description',
    'short_description',
    'weight',
    'collection_year',
    'lining_color',
   'material'
   .......SO on
```

Comment: I will be back to you after experiment @lucky

Comment: @BilalUsean - Sure

Comment: Yeah but this is just the export when you import the CSV again it won't update those attributes

Comment: @StevieG Do you find any solution for import?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal I was forced to write a script to combine those custom attributes back into the `additional_attributes` column in the correct format and stripping out special characters

Comment: Thanks @StevieG. I Will try to apply same on my project.

Comment: @Bilal Usean, is it working?

Answer (score 5):

This formula works in Excel, assuming no values have commas.

`=IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(H5, SUM(LEN(H5)-FIND("material=", H5)- LEN("material="), 1)), IFERROR(FIND(",", RIGHT(H5, SUM(LEN(H5)-FIND("material=", H5)- LEN("material="), 1)))-1, LEN(RIGHT(H5, SUM(LEN(H5)-FIND("material=", H5)- LEN("material="), 1))))), "")`

Just replace H5 and "material" with the appropriate cell and key.