# Do you have to use additional_attributes in Magento 2 product import or can you still create a separate field?

Tags: magento2, attributes, importexport

Instead of merging a bunch of fields in my import csv can I keep them separate?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for custom attributes you have to use the `additional_attributes` column. Unfortunately you cannot add columns to the CSV anymore.

Comment: thanks :-) this answer suitable for my question also http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110505/custom-attributes-in-separate-coloumn-while-export-magento-2-0-8

Comment: This is possible now with bss extension

Comment: Why? I feel like there is confusion between import and export. For export - yes, all additional attributes exported by default to additional_attributes and only like that. But any attribute which exists on M2 can be imported also as a separate column or i misunderstood here?

Comment: Last time I checked was Magento 2.0, so it might have changed (or I did something wrong)

Answer (score 0):

yes,If can create custom attribute through  programmatically than you can add columns to the CSV while importing.