# Magento 2 - Import custom product attributes through csv, can I import them using individual columns?

Tags: product-attribute, import, importexport, import-products, product-import

I was able to export the custom filterable product attributes into individual columns in CSV file using BSSCommerce export extension. Now I have a large amount of data need to update.I have searched around the forum and found different answers. I would like to confirm the definite answer if Magento 2 (i'm using 2.2.6) default import allow us to **import** custom product attributes through csv with **individual columns**(using custom attribute names), or everything need to go under "additional_attributes" column?

For example: Can I import it like below:

```
SKU   | custom-attr1 | custom-attr2 | custom-attr3
shirt |  blue        | xl           | men
```

or does it has to be like:

```
SKU   | additional_attributes
shirt | custom-attr1=blue,custom-attr2=xl,custom-attr3=men
```

some related questions i found, but can't find the definitely answer for import.

> [Do you have to use additional_attributes in Magento 2 product import or can you still create a separate field?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130196/do-you-have-to-use-additional-attributes-in-magento-2-product-import-or-can-you)
>
> [custom attributes in separate coloumn while export? - Magento 2.0.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110505/custom-attributes-in-separate-coloumn-while-export-magento-2-0-8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Magento default Import Export available at (System > Data Transfer > Import/Export).

Yes you need to specify all inside "additional_attributes" like "gift_wrapping_available=Use config,must_ship_freight=0,narendra=i am test entry on 24 march,narendra_attribute_2=Test1,ship_separately=0".

You can also import using individual column also like add a new column in exported CSV "narendra":"testing" and it should reflect in corresponding attribute value. But in this case you can delete that attribute from additional_attributes

For better understanding you can export CSV containing all products from (System > Data Transfer > Export) section and perform import using same CSV from (System > Data Transfer > Import) on selecting appropriate option in "Import Behaviour".

Let me know if you face any issue in this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i have downloaded the exported csv and delete all columns (keep only "SKU"column, and add "custom-attr1" column, but the import won't take it. Is there a minimum columns that i need to keep in the file for import update? ( i didn't have to for magento 1.9).

Comment: my concern is when using additional_attributes column, i had experienced my attributes got cutoff due to the long length of the csv cell (some of the custom attributes contain html formatted description) ( not sure if it's Microsoft excel issue, or the exported file issue).