# How do i get category ID in final_price.phtml and hide price accordingly in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, php, price, phtml

this is my current final_price.phtml file. the line

> $category = $product->getCategoryIds();
>   is causing error

I'm trying to get the category_id of the current product, and check if it's in $hiddenCategories array. If it is in the hiddenCategories, i would like to hide the price for that item.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;

?>

<?php 
/*get category id*/
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    //$productId = $product->getId();
    $category = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/   //this is the line causing problem
    $hiddenCategories = array('375','376','377','378','379','380','381','382','383','384','385','386','387','388','389');
    //$category = $block->getCategoryIds();
        //if ($categories AS $category) {
        //if (in_array($category, $hiddenCategories)) {
            /*dont' show price*/
        //  break;
        //   }
?>
<?php if (!in_array($category, $hiddenCategories)): /*only show price if category is not in array*/?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl() ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; /*end don't show price*/?>
```

Comment: what error you are facing ??

Comment: it show the page out of content. Am I suppose able to get the category id this way? thanks

Comment: I think yes you are doing right but there is some fatal error, can check by ctrl+u . Enable development mode and uncomment this line ini_set('display_errors', 1); in (app/bootstrap.php)

Comment: can you help me check my update code. i think it is not returning error now, but not making any effect on hiding price.

Comment: do you know how can i resolve this "1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox\Interceptor::$_productFactory in /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 110"

Comment: let me try to generate same here. Let me know what exact are you doing. Why are you using object manager directly ? Did you overide final_price.phtml let me know its path ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the cat_id of the current product and check if it's in $hiddenCategories array. If it is in the hiddenCategories, then try to hide the price for that item. I copied the final_price.phtml from /vendor folder to my theme folder "/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml". The only solutions i found to get the cat ids are using object manager, that's why but i would like to avoid it.

Comment: Yes I identified your problem have a look at my answer hope that will work for you.

Comment: I think you should not use using OM in any case. Magento provides  ViewModels using which you can include any custom logic and call easily. Although I think your problem will be resolved with the below code but you can search for ViewModels. Let me know if you still face any issue in this

Comment: thank you, i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try doing this way:

```
$hiddenCategories = array('375','376','377','378','3','379','380','381','382','383','384','385','386','387','388','389');
$categories = $block->getSaleableItem()->getCategoryIds();
```

Change your condition like this:

```
<?php if (!empty(array_intersect($categories, $hiddenCategories))): ?>
```

You can not use in_array as both are array so you need to find if there is any intersection between the two arrays.

Try using this way and let me know if you face any issue.

Also there can be more than one final_price.phtml called for various product types so make sure you check in all cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! this works wonderfully. I made it too complicated then it is. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that you made it done :)

Comment: do you happen to know if i can update individual custom attribute value through csv? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266887/magento-2-import-custom-product-attributes-through-csv-can-i-import-them-usin

Comment: I have reverted please check and let me know if that works for you.