# Why has Magento 2 made it harder for shop owners to update the exported product csv?

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 has now merged all custom attributes in a field called `additional_attributes`.

That has made it difficult for many shop owners to edit these fields as they have to sift through many attributes separated by commas or pipes. It has made it very difficult for shop owners to edit these files without doing some heavy processing.

Why was it done?

Comment: Well. I'm facing same issue. But this how it is build. We need to use it what has given. If it dosen't match as per our requirement we need to customize as simple as that http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110505/custom-attributes-in-separate-coloumn-while-export-magento-2-0-8

Comment: The problem with that "solution" is that you cannot import that file that is exported. So if you make a change to one of your additional attribute fields it will not update on the magento side.

Comment: It works fine with Import/Export with Attributes. Give more detail if needed

Comment: Export the CSV. Then update one of the attributes. Then import. That attribute will not be updated.